# Sonata admin bundle поле типа коллекция не удаляется

Tags: php, symfony

Имеется сущность Product и к нему соответственно ProductAdmin. У Product имеется отношение one-to-many к характеристикам этого продукта(ProductCharacteristic). Я хочу сделать так, чтобы в представлении формы редактирования можно было менять значения коллекции ProductCharacteristic. В ProductAdmin регистрирую метод по конструированию вида формы редактирования Product:

```php
    public function configureFormFields(FormMapper $form)
    {
        $form
            ->with('Продукт', ['class' => 'col-md-4'])
                ->add('name')
                ->add('category', EntityType::class, [
                    'class' => Category::class,
                    'choice_label' => 'name',
                ])
            ->end()
            ->with('Характеристики', ['class' => 'col-md-8'])
                ->add('characteristics', CollectionType::class, [
                    'type_options' => [
                        'delete' => true, // TODO НЕ РАБОТАЕТ!!!
                    ]
                ],
                    [
                        'edit' => 'inline',
                        'inline' => 'table',
                        'sortable' => 'position',
                        'limit' => 7,
                    ])
            ->end();
    }
```

Все вроде работает, НО! нет возможности удалить значения добавляемые в список. Информацию беру отсюда https://sonata-project.org/bundles/core/master/doc/reference/form_types.html#collectiontype
На скрине видно отсутствие кнопки delete.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

У класса `Product` в аннотации `@ORM\OneToMany()` нужно добавить свойство `orphanRemoval=true`. Это должно решить проблему

Comment: Добавил, кеш сбросил, не помогло)

Answer (score 0):

В общем частично решил проблему - отсутствовала строка с правами на удаление):

```yaml
# ...

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_PRODUCT_CHARACTERISTIC_ROOT:
            - ROLE_ADMIN_PRODUCT_CHARACTERISTIC_LIST
            - ROLE_ADMIN_PRODUCT_CHARACTERISTIC_EDIT
            - ROLE_ADMIN_PRODUCT_CHARACTERISTIC_VIEW
            - ROLE_ADMIN_PRODUCT_CHARACTERISTIC_CREATE
            - ROLE_ADMIN_PRODUCT_CHARACTERISTIC_DELETE
        ROLE_ADMIN: [ ROLE_PRODUCT_CHARACTERISTIC_ROOT ]
```

Почему частично? Потому, что странное какое-то удаление, т.е. я могу удалить строку из списка только после того как отмечу строку чекбоксом delete и отправлю запрос update на сервер. Не очень как мне кажется решение, было бы приятнее, например, напротив каждой строки иметь кнопку delete и при ее нажатии удалять всю строку из формы. Т.е. зачем нагружать сервер для удаления случайно добавленной строки?)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]